# Linux - fanotify, but for exec()?

Tags: linux, exec, fanotify

Is there a facility like fanotify, but for exec() operations? Something like [kauth in MacOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2127/_index.html), but in userland.

fanotify only seems to notify on (and allow/deny) file open/close/read/write.

I've seen code that can notify on fork and exec by [other means](http://bewareofgeek.livejournal.com/2945.html) (also [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20131003100847/http://netsplit.com/2011/02/09/the-proc-connector-and-socket-filters/)), but there is no way to allow or deny an exec. Also, it seems there are drawbacks to this approach, because not all kernels are compiled with netlink/proc connector, and it can get overwhelmed with events.

Comment: How exactly would this work in userland? Seems to me this is something that could only be implemented in the kernel.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a userland interface I could use for some pre-existing functionality in the kernel, like the netlink code in the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Linux finally added this feature to fanotify in kernel 5.0 (shipped in e.g. Ubuntu 19.04).

See `man 2 fanotify_mark` for details. The relevant flags are `FAN_OPEN_EXEC` and `FAN_OPEN_EXEC_PERM`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), a Linux kernel module which provides the enforcement of fine-grained security policies, like who or what gets to execute a certain file.

Comment: Does it have an API of some kind, or is it just setup through configuration files?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out what is possible with this API, though. Would it be possible for me to write a module that would get notified of an exec, and then return an access decision to selinux? Or, is the API more for reading/building a static configuration?

Examples I've seen using libselinux are projects like SE-PostgreSQL, and from my reading they use it to comply with the access control that is already setup in selinux.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "Process Events Connector" is what you are looking for. This interface will allow you to receive notifications of fork, exec, and setuid/setguid events.

Read more at LWN (https://lwn.net/Articles/157150/) and a great blog article (not mine) at http://netsplit.com/the-proc-connector-and-socket-filters.